# Determining Vector Spaces Via Drfinition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm practicing some linear algebra (am very new to the subject) and I came across this problem:

```
The set of square matrices with 3 rows (and thus 3 colums), endowed with law + (which 
represents addition of matrices ) and law ·(which represents the product of matrices) is: 
1) a vector space 2) not a vector space 3) none of the above
```

I feel like this is testing me on the definition of a vector space, which I understand to be a set of vectors that can be added together or multiplied by a scalar. So how would I answer this then?

Comment: As you suggest, apply the definition.  Just check each property one by one.

Comment: I think there is even a case to be made for answer 3). If you have a field K and a set A with an operation $+ \colon A \times A \to A$ and an operation $\cdot \colon K \times A \to A$, you can check if $(A,+,\cdot)$ is a $K$-vector space by checking the axioms of a vector space. But here you don't even have the correct structure; you have a set $A$, an operation $+ \colon A \times A \to A$ and an operation $\cdot \colon A \times A \to A$. So, the axioms of a vector space cannot be 'true' or 'false' in this structure; they have no interpretation in this structure at all.

Comment: @Magdiragdag: Indeed, this is what I was thinking, because I found myself reading the question several times, wondering how scalar multiplication is defined and also what is the point of specifying matrix multiplication, and before reading the comments I decided 3), but thinking that the question is somewhat too tricky in my opinion. Indeed, even if scalar multiplication were mentioned, there's the issue of what types of numbers are the matrix entries (maybe only nonzero numbers can be used, maybe the operation of addition on the "numbers" isn't commutative, etc.).

Comment: @Magdiragdag Thank you! do you mean we have set A with operation +: A + A --> A? Also, can you please explain the last sentence a little please, it confuses me.

Comment: Yes, you are given an operation $+ \colon A \times A \to A$ (namely matrix addition) and an operation $\cdot \colon A \times A \to A$ (namely matrix multiplication). For the last sentence: one of the axioms of a vector space is that 'for all $a,b \in K$ and all $v \in A$, $a \cdot (b \cdot v) = ab \cdot v$' (and there are others involving the scalar multiplication). This statement is meaningless in your context, because your setting does not define a scalar multiplication; you have $\cdot \colon A \times A \to A$, but not $\cdot \colon K \times A \to A$.

Comment: I'm not understanding the +: A x A --> A. Wouldn't it be +: A + A --> A? Or am I misunderstanding? And is the idea that we can't say conclusively if it is a vector space or not because we are unaware of the properties of A and we don't have a scalar multiplying A --> A, but instead A with the product on itself (A x A --> A) so, we are unaware what the scalar can be?